# VBA variable in the loop

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a lot of fields TextBox1 TextBox2 TextBox3 ....
I want to fill the array with data from the fields.

```
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() 
Dim Schild(32, 32) As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim prompt_deti As String

For i = 1 To UBound(Schild)
    Schild(i, i + 1) = Me.TextBox(i).Text
    Schild(i, i) = Me.TextBox(i).Text
    prompt_deti = prompt_deti & Schild(i, i) & Schild(i, i + 1) & Chr(10)
Next i

MsgBox prompt_deti

End Sub
```

Eror method or data member not found!

Schild(i, i + 1) = Me.TextBox **(i)** .Text

How to set this variable?
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply can't refer to a textbox this way. 
If there really are a lot of textboxes, you could consider to place the data in a table, in stead of all those textboxes. That way you can loop trough the tablerows.

Comment: Thank you!
But how to insert a table into the form?
I have a regular building panel.

Comment: @КириллЩербаков,  you 'link' your form to a table by setting the datasource - properties of the form. So 1) edit the form, 2) go to the properties, 3) check that you have the properties of the main-form, not the header, footer, etc.  4) in the datasource property you'll find a dropdownlist of all tables.